# Run ajax request only when user has filled in all required fields

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any way that I can call an ajax request only when the user has filled in all required fields? I have three fields for an event title, a list and a job title. Once all of these fields have been filled in I want to fire an ajax request to get the data that I want, but I don't know how to add an event listener to check if all these fields have values? Obviously users may change their input so I need to be checking whether all fields are filled in all the time before running the search.

This is how the data to search with is being obtained:

```
$('#event').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'search.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        event_title: request.term,
                        type: 'event'
                    },
                    success: function(events) {
                        response($.map(events, function (event) {
                            return {
                                label: event.date + "| " + event.title + "[" + event.short_name + "]",
                                value: event.title,
                                id: event.id
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 1
        });

        $("#event").on("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {
            $("#event_id").val(ui.item.id);
        });

        $("#list").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "search.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        list_name: request.term,
                        type: 'list'
                    },
                    success: function (lists) {
                        response(lists);
                        response($.map(lists, function (list) {
                            return {
                                label: list.l_name,
                                value: list.l_name,
                                id: list.id
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("#list").on("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {
            $("#list_id").val(ui.item.id);
        });
```

I then want to perform an ajax request using the data from those fields - but a user may obviously change those fields and they will start of blank.

Comment: Why don't you call a function to check if everything is alright, and if so, that same function does the Ajax request?

Comment: I did make a function `checkFieldsComplete();` that runs after updating the id fields on autocompleteselect and onkeyup, but it seems really inefficient? Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: Inefficient how? Are you talking about visible delay or 'in theory' checking every time seems like a lot of work? If it's the latter then you need not worry as it really isn't much work... if you're actually experiencing a visible delay then please post some code as it shouldn't be the case

Comment: More that it seems like a lot of hard work. I'm also unsure of how to allow the user to alter their input - once all fields have been filled in it runs the request, but it won't send again if they change their input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I suggest you try something similar to this...
This is to demonstrate the idea, you'd probably want to implement a delay to the input function so it doesn't call for every character that's entered into the third input. Also FYI the xhr.abort() method tells it to stop listening for previous  calls returning if a subsequent one is called. Good luck

```
<input id="first" class="linked-input"/>
<br/><br/>
<input id="second" class="linked-input"/>
<br /><br/>
<input id="third" class="linked-input"/>


$('.linked-input').on('input', function () {
    var firstVal = $("#first").val();
    var secondVal = $("#second").val();
    var thirdVal = $("#third").val();

    if (firstVal != "" && secondVal != "" && thirdVal != "") {
        AjaxValidate.call(firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal);
    }
});

var AjaxValidate = {
    call: function (firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal) {
        if (typeof this.xhr !== 'undefined') {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }

        this.xhr = $.ajax({
          url: 'search.php',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            first: firstVal,
            second: secondVal,
            third: thirdVal,
            type: 'event'
          },
          success: function (events) {
            response($.map(events, function (event) {
                return {
                  label: event.date + "| " + event.title + "[" + event.short_name + "]",
                  value: event.title,
                  id: event.id
                }
              }));
            }
        });
    }
};
```